How do I fix the "Formula parse" error? (Google Sheets)
I am trying to write a formula that references a cell (For example C1) which contains the name of the sheet I want referenced. I then want to pull from that sheet any numbers that were recorded between certain dates that I have recorded on my "Dates" sheet. But I am getting the "Formula parse error". What do I need to fix with the following formula?
=SUMIFS(INDIRECT(C1&"!C:C"),INDIRECT(C1&"!A:A"),">="&Dates!$G$2,INDIRECT(C1&"!A:A),"<="&Dates!$G$3"))

Ive tried looking up lots of different help guides but from what I can tell I am doing exactly as they are telling me.
Thanks!

Your quotes are off and you have an extra bracket at the end. Try:
=SUMIFS(INDIRECT(C1&"!C:C"),INDIRECT(C1&"!A:A"),">="&Dates!$G$2,INDIRECT(C1&"!A:A"),"<="&Dates!$G$3)


Awesome thank you so much. Worked like a dream.
